# Equating components of forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

I have a doubt.

Assume there is a pendulum which is currently at one of its end points (velocity=0 m/s) and the angle which it makes with the vertical is $\theta$. The forces acting on it will be Tension (T) and weight (mg). T acts radially inwards and mg acts vertically downwards.

If we take the components along the direction of T, we get the equation as $T=mgcos\theta$.

But if we decide to take the components along gravity, we get the equation $Tcos\theta=mg$.

Using these equations for further calculating the value of T will give different  answers, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the endpoints the mass is stationary ($v=0$) but its acceleration is not zero. There is a resultant force on it acting tangentially towards the equilibrium point.

At the endpoint there is no acceleration radially so there is no component of the resultant force radially. The radial components of the 2 forces balance : $T=mg\cos\theta$ is correct **at the endpoints**.

(Note that this is not true at other points along the trajectory where $v \ne 0$. Then the mass **is** accelerating radially so there must be a radial component of the resultant force to provide centripetal acceleration $a=\frac{v^2}{r}$.)

The resultant tangential force has a component in the vertical direction (as well as the horizontal direction) so the forces do not balance vertically (nor horizontally) : $T\cos\theta=mg$ is **not correct**.

It is only when an object is **not accelerating** in a particular direction (ie either at rest or moving with constant velocity in this direction) that you can balance components of force in this direction. If there is some acceleration, you can only balance forces in the direction perpendicular to the acceleration.

Comment: thanks a lot! I wasn't considering the tangential acceleration.